# Object reference in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I'm learning how to use object in javascript like below codes.

```
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
let arr2 = [4, 5, 6];
let arr3 = [10];
let arr4 = [...arr1, ...arr2, ...[7,8,9], ...arr3];

function myFunc() {
    let result = 0;
    let obj = {};
    let arr = [];
    for (let value of arguments) {
        result += value;
        obj.keys = value;
        arr.push(obj);
    }
    return [result, arr]; 
}

console.log(myFunc(...arr4)[0]);
console.log(myFunc(...arr4)[1]);
```

I expected the result like this;

    `[ { keys: 1 },
      { keys: 2 },
      { keys: 3 },
      { keys: 4 },
      { keys: 5 },
      { keys: 6 },
      { keys: 7 },
      { keys: 8 },
      { keys: 9 },
      { keys: 10 } ]`

But the result is like that:

    `55
    [ { keys: 10 },
      { keys: 10 },
      { keys: 10 },
      { keys: 10 },
      { keys: 10 },
      { keys: 10 },
      { keys: 10 },
      { keys: 10 },
      { keys: 10 },
      { keys: 10 } ]`

I guess that's a reference problem. Last 'value' is 10, so all values changed 10. I understood but, I can't fix the bug. How can I obtain a result what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create your `obj` variable inside the loop, otherwise you keep using the same object for each iteration:

```
function myFunc() {
    let result = 0;
    let arr = [];
    for (let value of arguments) {
        let obj = {};
        result += value;
        obj.keys = value;
        arr.push(obj);
    }
    return [result, arr]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a single object before your `for` loop and then, each time you go around the loop, you modify its `keys` property.

You need to create a new object each time you go around the loop.

Move the line of code which creates it so it is inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

use loop like

```html
var myStringArray = ["Hello","World"];
var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    alert(myStringArray[i]);
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are manipulating the same object `obj` over the loop, and push it 10 times. Eventually all elements in `arr` points to the same object.

Try declare `obj` inside the loop, or simply `arr.push({keys: value})`.

Answer (score 0):

"arr.push(obj);" in you case adds the same object obj many times, you have to initialize it inside the loop:

`for (let value of arguments) {
    result += value;
    let obj = {keys: value};
    arr.push(obj);
}`

Comment: You're right. I made object obj many times.I didn't realize. Thank you.